# 80s or 90s book. Not quite human man tries to discover his origin in a jungle environment

Tags: story-identification, clones

I recall a story where a man with no memory wakes up in a jungle-ish type area maybe along a river. He eventually meets a woman who is also not quite human (Maybe they have leaves instead of hair, or their skin is more like bark)

I think the area where he wakes up, is littered with many miss-formed and decaying bodies, many not even remotely human looking.

The pair together try to figure out who they are, and where they came from. They make their way up river, maybe having problems with very strange plants, animals along the way, and maybe some much more deformed humans who attack them. Eventually they come to a cave (source of the river?) with a crack to one side leading into an underground room/bunker/chamber.

In the room are vats/bays/cylinders where humans are apparently being grown. But most are not grown correctly. With clear defects in their form/structure. Machines are checking them and dumping out the ones near completion who are defective. (The source of the miss-formed bodies where they woke up.)

They start interacting with the computer running the place to try to discover what is going on and who they are.

If I recall correctly, The place is a cloning facility that was built long ago (10,000+ years?) but the chamber has since been breached by roots of plants growing through the walls/ceiling.

[I think the place was built to restart human population after an extinction level event wiped out most living things, and enough time had passed for the Earth to recovered enough to support life again.]

But the entry of the roots of plant life into the facility have contaminated the growing tanks, or the growth nutrients, or the egg/sperm source, so that everything comes out contaminated (some like the man and woman only a little, others greatly deformed) and is disposed of by the computer as not viable or close enough to human to be acceptable. I think it has been doing this for many years.

Comment: Is this a novel or  short story?

Comment: Pretty sure it was a novel

Comment: This sounds very familiar. I'm fairly certain I have read this a long time ago (at least 20-25 years ago). Unfortunately I can't recall more details either.